# CSS Combi Selections

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors

I am wondering if there is an easier way to target the following css class, because it could cause a little bit of bloat:

I have different single pages, where I want to disable a sticky header effect, because an other element is used to be fixed on that pages. Up to now I select those class by using:

```
.page-id-xx .header-is-sticky .header {
position: static; 
}
```

If I want to disable the sticky header on 20 pages I am ending up to use the selectors class above 20 times, but only the page-id-xx will change. It'd look like this:

```
.page-id-1 .header-is-sticky .header,
.page-id-2 .header-is-sticky .header,
.page-id-3 .header-is-sticky .header,

and so on ...
```

I am wondering, if there is a more intelligent way to target the .header class, maybe with the help of some combiselectors? Or is there a quick javascript snippets? Maybe an if loop by checking for the ID of the element (#subnav), which should be sticky alternativly to the header on that pages?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

**Possibly Unnecessary Specificity?**

Do you absolutely need the parent selector (i.e. `page-id-n`), if not, then obviously the following would be quite a bit more elegant :

```
.header-is-sticky .header {
     position: static; 
}
```

**Taking Advantage of CSS Selectors**

CSS provides a series of [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) that can be used to target certain elements depending on various constraints for their attributes. The starts-with and contains selectors should work for your needs here.

```
/* This will match any element that has a class attribute that starts with "page-id" */
[class^="page-id"] .header-is-sticky .header {
    position: static; 
}

/* This will match any element that has a class attribute that contains "page-id" */
[class*="page-id"] .header-is-sticky .header {
    position: static; 
}
```

Comment: Hi Rion, thanks for your fast reply. Yes, the page-id-xx is needed to identify the pages, where the header should not to be sticky anymore. On the other pages the header should continue to behave sticky, thats the point. Every page has its unique page-id by adding a number after the id, even the pages where the header should continue to be sticky (therefore the classes are named page-id-1, page-id-2, page-id-3 ... etc.). Therefore I am afraid, one global argument for the class "page-id" won't solve it, cause every page gets its unique id with the added number :(

Comment: Then it's likely that the CSS selector approach should work for you. It's worth noting that the "starts with" will only work if your page class is the first one present on your element, however the "contains" one should work as expected.

Comment: I gave it a try and ended up that the sticky header was globally disabled, cause every page has the "page-id" class. For example I have 100 (sub)pages and every page of them has page-id at the beginning I just want to disable the sticky header from page-id-1 until page-id-20 (of 100). The pages with the id 21-100 should still have a sticky header cause there won't be an other element  to be sticky. Is there a way to target the sticky element of the page 1-20 and define in that case the css rule according to the .header class? Thanks for your patience ;)

Comment: Sadly I'm not familiar with one that would only apply to a specific range (i.e. pages 1-20). You could likely resort to a tiny snippet of Javascript to accomplish this (i.e. parse the page number, depending on it's value apply your header-is-sticky class to the appropriate element). But purely with CSS, I don't know if it's going to be possible without explicitly hardcoding the pages you need.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so. If there are any ideas left, just let me know. And thank you very much for the hint with the combi selectors. I think, I could use them in other circumstances. Never potter at this up to now :) Have a nice day, Rion!